# Javascript jQuery skipping optional params

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

1 line of JavaScript code

```
$.post('/blah', { comment_id: 1, description: ... });
```

For some reason, the call is not made as a JS call and per [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), the `post` method allows for 2 more optional params, `success` and `dataType`. I would like to skip `success` and set `dataType` to `script`. I tried this and it gave me an error

```
$.post('/blah', { comment_id: 1, description: ... }, ,"script");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `null` or `undefined`:

```
$.post('/blah', { comment_id: 1, description: ... }, null,"script");

// use void for undefined (because undefined can be reassigned)...
$.post('/blah', { comment_id: 1, description: ... }, void 0,"script");
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that `void` is an operator!

Comment: @Igor: yep, it's a common misconception that `void` is a function :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is invalid Javascript. If you want to skip a parameter, you have to pass a `null` value instead:

```
$.post('/blah', { comment_id: 1, description: 'Blah' }, null, "script");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass null for the default parameter.